# What is wrong with this in detecting if a string contains numeric characters?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool is_number(const string& s);

int main (void)
{
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    if ( is_number(s) )
    {
         cout<<"Not a proper string\n";
    }
    else 
        cout<<"Is a proper string\n";
}
bool is_number(const string& s)
{
    string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while (it != s.end() && isdigit(*it)) ++it;
    return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
}
```

I made this program to detect if the input that I am giving contains a numeric character or not. This works fine if I give the input as `abc` and `123` but when I give the input as `a1`, it still shows it is proper string whereas it should show it is not a proper string. Why is this happening?
Thanks!

Comment: You've stepped through in a debugger already, right?

Comment: There are far less confusing ways to write this function, it could be a good time to try one of them.

Comment: also, the name is quite confusing. Maybe something like `has_digits` is more telling what it should do?

Answer (score 4):

`is_number` is checking every position of the string and returning true if they are all digits. The following function will instead check if any position in the string contains a digit:

```
bool is_number(const string& s)
{
    bool flag = false;
    string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while (it != s.end()) {
        if (isdigit(*it)) flag = true;
        ++it;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Note: `std::all_of`.

Comment: Be careful, std::string is not aware of character sets like Unicode. But I suppose that you only allow ASCII coded arabic numbers, so that you won't run into this problem.

Comment: This is a slightly better way to check that *all* characters are numeric; but the OP wants to check whether *any* character is numeric.

Comment: @degrg, I don't understand. Your code still doesnt solve my problem.

Comment: @user3776323 I made a revision which fixes the function. Note that is_number is not a great name for this function, since a1 is not a number

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `string::find_first_not_of`:

```
bool is_number(const string s) {
    return s.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == string::npos
}
```

Comment: This still has the same problem. Try inputting a1. It shows that it is a proper stirng.

Comment: @user3776323 just tried "1" and it returns `true`.

Comment: I think OP wants `s.find_first_of("0123456789") != string::npos`.

Comment: @Jarod42 this will be `true` for `a1` which OP says is wrong

Comment: @PaulEvans: I understand that "123", "a1" should be `"Not a proper string\n"` (but OP's code fails for "a1").

Comment: @Jarod42 properly returns `false` for `"a1"` and `true` for `"123"` as OP wants, OP didn't test it properly...

Answer (score 0):

if s contains numeric characters,the iterator 'it' will never be s.end();

So you should

```
bool is_number(const string& s)
{
    if (s.empty())
        return false;
    string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
    while (it != s.end() && isdigit(*it))
    {
        ++it;
    }
    return it == s.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, we can use string stream :)

```
bool is_number(const std::string& s)
{
    std::istringstream istr(s);
    double n = 0.0;
    if(istr >> n)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

This will work 100% correctly and you can change double to int

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
bool has_digit(const std::string& s) {
    return s.find_first_of("0123456789") != std::string::npos;
}
```

or

```
bool has_digit(const std::string& s) {
    return std::any_of(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c){ return isdigit(c); });
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/euYr5W)

Answer (score 0):

I would use standard algorithm `std::all_of`. It is more expressive.

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

bool IsNumber( const std::string &s )
{
    return 
    !s.empty() &&
    std::all_of( s.begin(), s.end(),
                        []( char c ) { return std::isdigit( c ); } );
}                    

int main() 
{
    std::string s;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << IsNumber( s ) << std::endl;

    s = '1';

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << IsNumber( s ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
false
true
```